# Strange results of TrafficStats/NetworkStatsManager APIs

Tags: android, network-programming

I developing Android app that should display per application network usage statistics. I use [TrafficStats APIs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/TrafficStats.html) on devices running Android versions prior 6 and [NetworkStatsManager APIs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/usage/NetworkStatsManager.html) on devices running Android 6 and newer.

My app displaying list of apps sorted by network usage in bytes.

I noticed that there always several system apps that have exactly the same value of network usage (for example if one has 31317179 rx byte then other will have exactly the same 31317179). Their pakage names is:

- com.google.android.syncadapters.contacts
- com.google.android.gms
- com.google.android.gsf
- com.google.android.gsf.login

but may vary per device/os version.
My question is why this happens? Is this bug in APIs? If this apps share same trafic somehow - is there way to get info about which processes has shared traffic for ability to group they?

My current code for TrafficStats is like this:

```
private List<TrafficInfo> getTrafficInfosByTrafficStatsAPI(PackageManager pm) {
    List<TrafficInfo> trafficlnfos = new ArrayList<>();
    List<PackageInfo> packinfos = pm.getInstalledPackages(PackageManager.GET_PERMISSIONS);
    for (PackageInfo info : packinfos) {
        String[] premissions = info.requestedPermissions;
        if (premissions != null && premissions.length > 0) {
            for (String premission : premissions) {
                if ("android.permission.INTERNET".equals(premission)) {
                    int uid = info.applicationInfo.uid;
                    long total = TrafficStats.getUidRxBytes(uid) + TrafficStats.getUidTxBytes(uid);
                    if (total > 0) {
                        TrafficInfo trafficInfo = new TrafficInfo();
                        trafficInfo.setName(getPackageName(pm, info));
                        trafficInfo.setPackageName(info.packageName);
                        trafficInfo.setTraffic(total);
                        trafficlnfos.add(trafficInfo);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    Collections.sort(trafficlnfos);
    return trafficlnfos;
}
```

Comment: They might use `android:sharedUserId` and have the same `uid`.

Comment: Thank you! I checked and this is right answer. They really have the same uid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`TrafficStats` reports traffic by UID. For most apps, there is one app per UID. For Googly apps, and system apps provided by the device manufacturer/custom ROM developer, there may be several apps per UID, courtesy of `android:sharedUserId`. I am not aware of any way to distinguish traffic by package within a UID. But, the code in your question will result in N records with the same traffic for N apps, when those N apps have the same UID.